# Object oriented design, interacting objects

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

This problem reminds me of the minigame Doodle God. There are several objects and some of them can interact with each other and form new objects. Each object is naturally its own class: water, fire, air, etc. These all inherit from the same base class. The water and fire objects, for example, could be combined to form an ash object which can be used in new combinations.

The problem is figuring out an elegant way to handle all the possible combinations. The most obvious, but horribly unmaintainable, solution would be creating a function that takes any two objects as parameters and uses a huge switch block to compare typenames and figure out what kind of object (if any) should be returned when these two interact. It is also important that combine(a, b) should always equal combine(b, a).

What would be a maintainable and efficient design for this scenario?

Comment: The best way is use Design Patterns. Take a look at Creational and Behavioral types http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: for the creation you can use a lookup table, you pass it the two objectId (e.g. "fire", "water") using as a key an object with an overriden equals. this way you can do: var key = new IdSet(doodle1.Name, doodle2.Name); String result = lookupTable[key]; with the given result you can create the resultant object. having a class for every object seems to much to me I'd rather have a general class since I doubt the doodles really do any specialization other than setting some parameters

Answer (score 2):

We had to take code for this in a game to collide items. We ended up going for a two dimensional structure that stored a bunch of delegate methods.

```
      | air            |  wind            | fire
air   |combine(air,air)|combine(air,wind) |combine(air,fire)
wind  |                |combine(wind,wind)|combine(wind,fire)
fire  |                |                  |combine(fire,fire)
```

with a bit of thinking, you only need to populate just over half of the combining matrix.

You could (for instance):

```
lookup = 
     new Dictionary<
            Tuple<Type, Type>,
            Func<ICombinable, ICombinable, ICombinable>();
lookup.Add(
   Tuple.Create(typeof(Air), typeof(Fire)),
   (air,fire) => return new Explosion());
```

Then have a single method:

```
ICombinable Combine(ICombinable a,ICombinable b)
{
    var typeA = a.GetType();
    var typeB = b.GetType();
    var typeCombo1 = Tuple.Create(typeA,typeB);
    Func<ICombinable,ICombinable,ICombinable> combineFunc;
    if(lookup.TryGetValue(typeCombo1, out combineFunc))
    {
        return combineFunc(a,b);
    }
    var typeCombo2 = Tuple.Create(typeB,typeA);
    if(lookup.TryGetValue(typeCombo2, out combineFunc))
    {
        return combineFunc(b,a);
    }
     //throw?
}
```

Comment: This should do the trick, thanks. It would most likely be best to return null instead of throwing since it is expected behaviour certain objects have no combination.

Answer (score 1):

All game objects are already designed in some way. They are either hardcoded or read at runtime from a resource.

This data structure can easily be stored in a `Dictionary<Element, Dictionary<Element, Element>>`.

```
var fire = new FireElement();
var water = new WaterElement();
var steam = new SteamElement();

_allElements = Dictionary<Element, Dictionary<Element,Element>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<Element, Dictionary<Element, Element>>
    {
        Key = fire,
        Value = new KeyValuePair<Element, Element>
        {
            Key = water,
            Value = steam
        }
    },
    new KeyValuePair<Element, Dictionary<Element, Element>>
    {
        Key = water,
        Value = new KeyValuePair<Element, Element>
        {
            Key = fire,
            Value = steam
        }
    }

}
```

When loading or defining the elements, you can just duplicate them, as there'll at most be a few hundred. The overhead is neglectable for the ease of coding IMO.

The keys of `_allElements` contain all existing, combinable elements. The value of `_allElements[SomeElement]` yields yet another dictionary, which you can access on the elment you wish to combine it with.

This means you can find the resulting element of a combination with the following code:

```
public Element Combine(Element element1, Element element2)
{
    return _allElements[element1][element2];
}
```

Which, when called as such:

```
var resultingElement = Combine(fire, water);
```

Yields `steam`, the same result as were `Combine(water, fire)` called.

Untested, but I hope the principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this is the right place for interfaces. With them you can avoid the big switch and each element  class can implement its own behaviour of interacting with another elemt class.

Comment: That's a helluva lot of interfaces. What about the other end of the relationship. If you combine (e.g.) air and fire, who is responsible for the outcome, or do they both implement a "combiner" (leading to redundancy)?

Answer (score -1):

I would propose using an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) returning a specific kind of interface, lets say `InteractionOutcome`. You would not escape the need of using a `switch-case` but you would end up with something much more maintenable using different factories for each "construction".

Hope I helped!